# How can I read a .csv file into Matlab in which each column corresponds to a date?

Tags: matlab, csv, import

---

### Original Raw Data

I have a .csv file which looks like this

```
Type,    Name,      2/18, 2/19, 2/20, 2/21
country, Australia, -3,  -6,   -3,   -1
country, Canada,    -5,   0,   -3,   -2
country, Germany,   11,   4,    3,    5
country, Ireland,    2,   0,    4,    1
state,   Alberta,    2,  10,    2,    1
```

and would like to read it into Matlab. You can see that the dates are comma separated across, and so each column is effectively a date in this original file.

---

### Ideal Result

I would like the result to be a Matlab table that looks like the following:

```
    date          Australia   Canada  Germany  Ireland  Alberta
    __________    _________   ______  _______  _______  _______

    18/Feb/2020   -3          -5      11        2        2
    19/Feb/2020   -6           0       4        0       10
    20/Feb/2020   -3          -3       3        4        2
    21/Feb/2020   -1          -2       5        1        1
```

so that I can access for example all of Germany's data using `my_table.Germany` and `my_table.date`.

---

### Current Situtaion

However, if I try to read the csv file using the `readtable()` function, I obtain the following:

```
    Type         Name           x2_18    x2_19    x2_20    x2_21
    _________    ___________    _____    _____    _____    _____

    "country"    "Australia"    -3       -6       -3       -1   
    "country"    "Canada"       -5        0       -3       -2   
    "country"    "Germany"      11        4        3        5   
    "country"    "Ireland"       2        0        4        1   
    "state"      "Alberta"       2       10        2        1
```

So I have a couple of problems:

1) I would like each column to correspond to a country/state name, not a day. The table somehow needs to be transposed.

2) The dates are being read in and assigned as the variable names of each column. They are in the format **x2_18** for example, but I would like them to be datetime objects, so that I can change the format to **18th Feb 2020**, for example.

How can I solve these problems?

Thank you!

---

(My Matlab version is R2017a)

**EDIT ---------------------------------------**

Max's answer pretty much solved my problem, except that `delimitedTextImportOptions()` was not available in my Matlab version. As workaround, I decided to read the first line only using `fgetl()` and use this to create the date vector. Finally, I read the rest of the file using `readtable()`, and build up the table manually as Max suggested. The code that worked for me is the following, which produced exactly the "Ideal Result" above:

```
fid = fopen(my_filename);
first_line = fgetl(fid);
Date = datetime(strsplit(first_line, ','),'InputFormat','MM/dd')';
fclose(fid);
Date([1 2]) = [];

opts = detectImportOptions(my_filename);
temp_table = readtable(filename,opts);
country = temp_table{:,2};

date_table = table(Date,'VariableNames',{'Date'});
data_matrix = temp_table{:,3:end}.';

data_table = array2table(data_matrix,'VariableNames', country);
data_full = [date_table,data_table];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to rotate the content of the file... this cannot be done with the normal import functions. So I read in everything first (as a cell) and build the input that you wanted in MATLAB. Have a look:

```
opts = delimitedTextImportOptions('NumVariables',6,'DataLines',1);
DatTbl = readtable('myfile.csv',opts);

% extract dates
Times = datetime(DatTbl{1,3:end},'InputFormat','MM/dd');
% extract country names
country = DatTbl{2:end,2};
% extract information
Info = str2double(DatTbl{2:end,3:end});

%% build table
% standard table
Tbl = [table(Times.'),array2table(Info.','VariableNames',country)]
% timetable
TimTbl = array2timetable(Info.','VariableNames',country,'RowTimes',Times)
```

You can choose if you want to have a standard [`table`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), or a [`timetable`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timetable.html) (introduces R2016b, so it should work for you =) ). It should work with more countries and more dates. The transposition is done while building the tables `Info.'` with `array2table`/`array2timetable`, which are required to split the matrix into individual columns  of the tables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to implement it, but it looks like the function delimitedTextImportOptions() isn't present in 2017a. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @teeeeee, you can probably use [`dlmread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) instead.

Comment: oh damn, sorry I wasn't aware of that. But @Hoki already helped=) thx

Comment: BTW, since R2018a, you can "transpose" a `table` using `rows2vars` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rows2vars.html

Comment: oh good to know @Edric. I'm not sure if that would reduce the code as we would need to transpose the csv file to make full use of the `delimitedTextImportOptions` rather than transposing the read-in table, right?